# Azure Pipeline AWS Powershell script task

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to use the powershell in my AWS Elastic Beanstalk to install some windows feature(ie. web sockets).

i found this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/awspowershell-module-script.html but I don't know and I cant find the task equivalent for this. currently in my pipeline I have this

```
      - task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.awsshellscript.awsshellscript@1
        displayName: 'Install Web Socket Protocol'
        inputs:
          scriptSource: 'inline'
          script: 'Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-WebSockets'
          awsCredentials: 'AWS-test'
          regionName: 'ap-southeast-2'
          applicationName: 'test'
          environmentName: 'test-staging'
```

but this one runs on the bash shell script. What is the equivalent task for powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Pipeline AWS Powershell script task

What you are looking for should be the extension [AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools):

> Tasks for Amazon S3, AWS Elastic Beanstalk, AWS CodeDeploy, AWS Lambda
>   and AWS CloudFormation and more, and **running commands in the AWS Tools
>   for Windows PowerShell module and the AWS CLI**.

After installing this extension, we could add the task AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script:

[image]

```
- task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.AWSPowerShellModuleScript.AWSPowerShellModuleScript@1
  displayName: 'AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script: '
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS-test'
    regionName: xxxx
    arguments: xxxx
    scriptType: inline
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you store `AWS-test`?

Comment: @MohamadShiralizadeh I know this is over a year old but for anyone who runs into this, `AWS-test` is set in the DevOps Project settings, in Service connections.